# IPA generated by Xcode 4.3.3 is bigger than Xcode 4.5 DP2

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4.3, xcode4.5

In **same** project, IPA generated by Xcode 4.3.3 is 4.1 MB, Xcode 4.5 DP2 makes it only 2.9 MB. After unzip and Show Package Content, only app executable file is different. Xcode 4.3.3 makes it 4.9 MB, Xcode 4.5 DP2 makes it 2.3 MB.

Why the difference?

Thanks.

Comment: Guess not since Xcode 4.6 is out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess, without installing Xcode 4.3.3 is that Xcode 4.5 DP2 removed the `ARMv6` binary from the ipa. Thus you are left with just the ARMv7 binary.